# Parse command output

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to only get the value associated to "cached" column of the `free -m` command. What is the most efficient way to achieve it? Something with `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this for memory cached value :

```
LANG=C /usr/bin/free -m | awk 'NR==2{print $7}'
```

Comment: This only prints "0"

Comment: So give us your output, seems different than mine

Comment: for me its column 7  /usr/bin/free -m | awk 'NR==2{print $7}'

Comment: I count to `$7`, too.

Comment: Yep. This is the correct answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the information from [the source](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?free%201) (on Linux):

```
awk '/^Cached:/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

This does get the value in kB (for me), so you could convert it for MB:

```
awk '/^Cached:/{print $2/1024}' /proc/meminfo
```